# WSO2 EI 7.0.2 is not completely open source?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 7.0.2 is not completely open source ? If I want to use it for commercial purpose do I've to purchase subscription 
As I can see it in there WSO2 [license](https://wso2.com/licenses/eula/3.0) agreement while downloading the same from [here](https://wso2.com/integration/#)
that for commercial purpose the subscription is required as below:

2.2 from below image
[image]

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binary you download from the website is under EULA. But you can build yourself a pack from the git repo[1] which is under Apache License.

[1] https://github.com/wso2/product-ei

Comment: Ok. Thank you. 
Is that git repo is same as what is provided in website ? Or there will be differences in it ?

Comment: It is the same.